# In Vim, how do I apply a macro to a set of lines?

Tags: vim, vim-macros

I have a file with a bunch of lines.  I have recorded a macro that performs an operation on a single line.  I want to repeat that macro on all of the remaining lines in the file.  Is there a quick way to do this?

I tried Ctrl+Q, highlighted a set of lines, and pressed @@, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Offtopic question: I wasn't aware of VIM macros ( or didn't wanted to be aware :P ) Do you have some nice "lazy reader" oriented link on VIM macros?

Comment: Sure, this: http://www.oreillynet.com/mac/blog/2006/07/more_vim_save_time_with_macros_1.html sums it up pretty well.

Comment: You can also check :he complex-repeat from inside vim

Answer (score 492, accepted):

Use the [normal](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:normal) command in Ex mode to execute the macro on multiple/all lines:

Execute the macro stored in register **a** on lines 5 through 10.

```
:5,10norm! @a
```

Execute the macro stored in register **a** on lines 5 through the end of the file.

```
:5,$norm! @a
```

Execute the macro stored in register **a** on all lines.

```
:%norm! @a
```

Execute the macro store in register **a** on all lines matching *pattern*.

```
:g/pattern/norm! @a
```

To execute the macro on visually selected lines, press **V** and the **j** or **k** until the desired region is selected. Then type `:norm! @a` and observe the that following input line is shown.

```
:'<,'>norm! @a
```

Enter *:help normal* in vim to read more.

Comment: Adding a : first doesn't allow me to use @

Comment: Yes it does. You type the whole thing on the line and then press enter.

Comment: Ah, it was the norm! part that I was missing.

Comment: Yes, :help normal in vim or the link I just added.

Comment: Anything to help a fellow non-emacs user!

Comment: Nice!! Beginner tip: use V then j/k to highlight the lines you want, then type just `:norm! @a`

Comment: To add to the very helpful tip from @KevinBourrillion, when pressing `:` after highlighting the lines, the Ex input line will instead read `:'<,'>` to which you will then add rest of what Kevin suggested. This will make the final command read: `:'<,'>norm! @a`.

Comment: I do not understand why the `!` is necessary at the end; other `norm` usages do not require it.

Comment: @GabeMoothart The `!` avoids user remapping of keys. You may not need it, but an answer that works for everyone requires it.

Comment: In emacs evil mode I get this error `/bin/bash: @a: command not found`. It works when I remove the `!`

Comment: Great examples. Run the macro up to a certain pattern? e.g. macro searches for "public class" and then I tell it to run to the next "^}" (end of class)? E.g. I need to renumber all the ProtoMember(id) numbers within a class and restart counter with each class.

Answer (score 66):

Use [global](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Power_of_g) to run the macro 'a' on all lines that contain 'pattern'

```
:g/pattern/normal! @a
```

For help, check: `:help global`.

Comment: Just for clarification for future users: this a global Ex command.

Answer (score 54):

You can also do this:

In normal mode:

```
[number of times to apply the macro] @ [register]
```

For example:

```
1000@q
```

Apply the macro in register q to the next 1000 lines.

> Update: the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/390194/2482570) is a lot better
>
> Update: as @kevinliu pointed out, you likely want to end the macro with a `j` to go to the next line.

Comment: This stops on the last line, and doesn't execute multiple time on the last line, which I was afraid of.

Comment: @Hubro, these answers from other users worked for me: `:%norm! @a` and `vGG :norm! @a`

Comment: For some reason, this worked awesomely, and the accepted answer didn't. My macro involved inserting a new line, doing stuff, and moving to the next line.

Comment: @jasonszhao yes same here. but is there anyway to not say 1000 but all lines till end.. and still take care of the new line, doing stuff, etc.

Comment: I think it should be pointed out that your macro must end with a `j` command to go down to the next line otherwise it will try to apply it to the same line.

Comment: @KevinLiu that is the important part, the author failed to point out in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a plugin called RangeMacro, does exactly what you want! For everyone that can't guess by the name, what it does: it repeats a recorded macro for each line in a given range, no matter if by visual selection or by a :40,50 / :+10

See http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3271