# In Vim, how to apply macro that involves making a new line to multiple lines

Tags: vim, macros

Given:

```
This is nearly identical 
My answer looks like an o
I am glad you did because
Thank you so much, romain
```

Desired output, just duplicate the line and add `2` at the end:

```
This is nearly identical 
This is nearly identical 2
My answer looks like an o
My answer looks like an o2
I am glad you did because
I am glad you did because2
Thank you so much, romain
Thank you so much, romain2
```

I have recorded a macro @q that will start from the first line, duplicate the line (cursor is now at the second line), append `2`, and then go to the next line (cursor is now at the third line). The macro works well if I just keep typing `@q` until the end of the file (never need to move the cursor, cursor movement is handled correctly by the macro).

however if I try to use `:'<,'>norm! @q` method ([seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390174/in-vim-how-do-i-apply-a-macro-to-a-set-of-lines)), I got this:

```
This is nearly identical 
This is nearly identical 2
This is nearly identical 22
This is nearly identical 222
This is nearly identical 2222
My answer looks like an o
I am glad you did because
Thank you so much, romain
```

Comment: As suggested, answered in vi.stackexchange.com: [in cmd mode, 99@q](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2984/36673)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your snippet, but with line numbers to help you see the problem:

```
1 This is nearly identical 
2 My answer looks like an o
3 I am glad you did because
4 Thank you so much, romain
```

The range is really just a list of line numbers, `[1, 2, 3, 4]` in this case, which means that your macro is applied on lines 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Since your macro adds a line below the current one, the line previously known as 2 is now 3:

```
1 This is nearly identical 
2 This is nearly identical 2
3 My answer looks like an o
4 I am glad you did because
5 Thank you so much, romain
```

and your macro is played on the actual line 2:

```
1 This is nearly identical 
2 This is nearly identical 2
3 This is nearly identical 22
4 My answer looks like an o
5 I am glad you did because
6 Thank you so much, romain
```

then on line 3:

```
1 This is nearly identical 
2 This is nearly identical 2
3 This is nearly identical 22
4 This is nearly identical 222
5 My answer looks like an o
6 I am glad you did because
7 Thank you so much, romain
```

then on line 4:

```
1 This is nearly identical 
2 This is nearly identical 2
3 This is nearly identical 22
4 This is nearly identical 222
5 This is nearly identical 2222
6 My answer looks like an o
7 I am glad you did because
8 Thank you so much, romain
```

In order to avoid that, you must mark every line in the range first. This is done with `:help :global`:

```
:'<,'>g/^/norm! @q
```

where `'<,'>g/^/` marks every line in the range and `norm! @q` executes the macro.

Comment: Thanks, however, 2 things: [1] my macro has 2 `j`s for going to the third line, but you are suggesting those movements don't have consequences, as the next macro execution won't be where the `j` will end up with, but where the new next line is, right? [2] need a link on explaining `g/^/`

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. There's already `:help :global` mentioned in the answer, what more do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try making the macro, and then `4@q`

I tried to recreate your macro, and ran `4@q`:

This is nearly identical
This is nearly identical 2
My answer looks like an o
My answer looks like an o2
I am glad you did because
I am glad you did because2
Thank you so much, romain
Thank you so much, romain2

This saves having to do a visual selection.